# Travel options out of Changi Airport late at night

Tags: trains, buses, singapore

I have a flight to SIN Changi that lands at around 11 PM. I assume it will take 1-1.5 hours to complete immigration formalities and reclaim baggage.

With that into consideration, what options do I have to go to the city, which are not taxis (too expensive), that is, preferably public transportation. I have to go to Little India.

I looked at the MRT rides, the last one leaves Changi at 00:06, and I think we are going to miss that one with almost full certainty.
[image]

Now, what about buses? I have no clue about them. Remember, I want to reach Little India. What options do I have that late at the night?

Or if I am missing anything, please let me know!
Thank You.

Comment: Those are actually not the right times, they are for connection to Pasir Ris (the terminus of the other eastern branch). The last train going downtown leaves at 23:18. So definitely no chance of catching that.

Comment: Have you been to Singapore before? The taxis there are, in my experience, inexpensive compared to other cities.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Normally a good option for you would likely be the hourly [City Shuttle](https://www.changiairport.com/en/airport-guide/transport/shuttle-services.html), which can take you to anywhere in downtown Singapore (including Little India) for a flat S$10.  Unfortunately, as @jcaron points out, the last service leaves at 11 PM.

Your best bet is thus installing the [Grab app](https://www.grab.com/sg/) (local Uber equivalent).  Regular Grabs tend to be cheaper than taxis, especially after midnight when regular taxis apply a 50% surcharge, and you can cut costs further with the [GrabShare carpooling service](https://www.grab.com/sg/inside-grab/stories/grabshare-weve-revamped-our-carpooling-service/).  Prices are dynamic though and around 11 PM is unfortunately peak hour at Changi, I'd guesstimate $30 for a solo Grab or $20 for a share but it's really going to depend even on things like which terminal, which day of the week, whether it's raining etc.

If you're *really* pinching pennies and make it through Immigration quickly enough, the [last bus 27 leaves Terminal 2 at 23:57 and you could transfer to bus 23](https://maps.app.goo.gl/4gKqGJGZtGfBqzJH6), which takes you directly to the north end of Little India.  If you have a contactless credit card, you can tap it to pay fares directly.  Now this is going to be a bit tricky if you're not familiar with Singapore, especially since you'll need to navigate between two bus stops to make the connection.  On the upside, even if you miss the transfer, you can still call a Grab and it'll likely be cheaper than taking one directly from the airport.

Comment: The last City Shuttle is at 23:00 so OP can’t make it.

Comment: @jcaron Crap! Well spotted, updated answer.

Comment: Good Grab estimate. I paid 28.80 SGD for  that trip (SIN to little India) with a solo Grab at 2:30am this week.

Answer (score 3):

If your flight lands at 23:00 or close to that, there are 2 possible scenarios.

1. You're on a plane from India, and are not flying First/Business class (ie you won't be in pole position when deplaning).

Tough luck. A plane full of Indians, who require a visa to visit Singapore, with only a few manual counters (as ICA has opened eGates to tourists from visa-free countries. You're in for a long wait indeed.

You're stuck with a taxi or a Grab. Buses close earlier than the MRT. There may be a couple of buses left to Punggol. That's about it.

2. Plane with mostly travellers from visa-free countries.

You'll have just about enough time to catch the last train. Hopefully your luggage will come out quickly enough, and will be waiting for you at the belt. And Customs won't single you out for secondary inspection of your luggage.

**UPDATE**

After jcaron's comment I checked and yeah, the 00:06 last train goes only to Pasir Ris, so not very useful. The last train for downtown, interchanging at Tanah Merah, is at 23:18, so you're SOL anyway.

Taxis and Grab are not very expensive anyway - would it be only because distances are short...

Comment: See my comment on the question re: last train times. Last train in the right direction is actually at 23:18, so that option does not seem possible at all.

Comment: Note that taxis have a surcharge for travel at those times, but it should still remain quite affordable... We're probably talking about something like SGD 50